# C# Unique Id in TreeView for Inventory Category System

Tags: c#, xml, treeview, linq-to-entities, categories

I am trying to make an Inventory/Warehouse application and I have tons of items that will be added every item has a category and some categories (if not all) will be sub-categorized.

I tried Import/Export TreeView from/to XML file then save the XML file in the database and everything is working fine.

The Treeview provides the user a UI to add/edit/remove category and sub-category.

Problem now is that I need to add a unique Id for every category either main category or sub-category then assign this Id to the item so that when the user selects a category or sub-category from the treeview it filters the item with with that category or sub-category based on the Id assigned, also if the user selects the main category it should filter all items and sub-category items.

I tried using hierarchyId in sql server but its not working in Framework Entities thats why I used an XML saved in a database.

Do I have to create a table with an identity column and add to it every category and sub-category then get this id value and save it my XML file ?

Or is there other technique for this problem ?

Comment: You can always use `GUID`.

Comment: I don't understand why you store XML. If you store category and sub-category in one table (which I think is the way to go) then a foreign key is al you need, don't you?

Comment: How will tell (for the sake of example) that category with Id = 1 has sub-category of Id 20, 21, 34 and those has another sub-category of Id 60,100,120, ..., etc ?

Comment: Well, that's just something like `Category.ParentCategoryId`.

Comment: @GertArnold I see what you mean; I have to make my own category node system. I am using XML because its easier to set and get data as I will be using LINQ-to-XML